Round off issue fortran90
I intend to extract single decimal number from a 5 decimal real number.
I have tried
program test_round
 implicit none
 real :: tempr
 
 tempr = nint(14.23456*10.0)/10.0
 print*,'rounded to 1 decimal =',tempr

end 

Output:
14.1999998
Desired:
14.2
I have tried 'floor' function too but in vain.
Can anyone please guide on how to obtain desired result?
Thank you.

There is no such number as 14.2 - as a binary floating point value.  The result you're getting is the actual result of the division by 10, as accurate as it can be in this representation.  Getting specific numbers of digits in the output is better done via format specifications - try print '(A,F5.1)','rounded to 1 decimal =',14.23456

Thank you @jasonharper. I need to compare two real numbers and that have similarity only upto the first decimal. That's why I wanted to round off to that. I found a work around like this: int(num1*10.) .eq. in(num2*10.).
